# Android Wakelock vs Alarm - Efficiently polling for data

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an Android application that needs to check for data every so often. For the context of this question I don't think it matters, but, I'm asking the device to give me bluetooth data every so often.

Apparently the Android device can go into a sleep mode... so even though I had my "**Hey! is there any new data!?**" code running as an intent service, that process apparently won't run when the Android phone / tablet decides it wants to go to sleep.

After learning about the above (yeah, I'm a noob), my approach was to acquire a CPU Wakelock when my bluetooth data service was started... and hold onto it indefinitely. This appears to work, but it seems to really hammer the battery life.

So, after MUCH googling and reading it seems really unclear to me what the best approach is for someone in my scenario.

- I want to be able to check periodically for some new data from my source (in this case it's Bluetooth data).
- I want to minimize battery usage

Do I keep a CPU wakelock open for the entire time my thread is constantly looking for new data?

Does using SystemClock.sleep(xxx); in a thread that is constantly looping with CPU wakelock help? Does that give some sort of battery saving for a thread that has an endless wakelock?

Should I throw away all this wakelock business and use some sort of alarm functionality?

The frequency for checking for new data can be something like 20 seconds....

**Check for new data**  |  **Sleep 20 secs** | **Check for new data**  |  **Sleep 20 secs**

I want my application to run indefinitely, **every so often** but also use minimal battery life.

Comment: I have used alarms for a similar job in my app but the time interval was a little more ~ 3 mins. It helped to save battery as compared to wake locks.You can try this approach but also reconsider the time duration of 20 secs as it is quite low

Comment: Okay, that is good to know... thank you :-)   Maybe there is some equation where the balance can be found, for example, if less than 156 seconds then use permanent wakelock, otherwise use alarm. Is there some information that describes when alarm vs wakelock is more efficient??...